# React Native Navigation bottomTabNavigater and Header

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I am trying to make an app navigation, with tabs on the bottom and some buttons on the header.

The set up I have at the moment is following:

AppNavigator.Js which has a SwitchNavigation for the login and signUp. Then a StackNavgation for the Mainapp, inside is the TabNavigator.

```js
const AppStack = createStackNavigator({
  Main: MainTabNavigator,
  Profile: ProfileScreen,
  UserSettings: SettingsScreen,
  Abo: AboScreen,
})

AppStack.navigationOptions = {
  headerRight: (
    <Button
      onPress={() => alert('This is a button!')}
      title="Info"
      color="#fff"
    />
  ),
}

{/* Navigation all the routes added here */}
export default createSwitchNavigator({
  Loading: AuthLoadingScreen,
  Welcome: WelcomeScreen,
  App: AppStack,
  Login: LoginScreen,
  SignUp: SignUpScreen,
  ForgotPassword: ForgotPasswordScreen,
});
```

MainTabNavigator.js in here I have the Tabs, each Tab is a StackNavigator.

```js
const NewsStack = createStackNavigator({
  News: NewsScreen,
});

NewsStack.navigationOptions = {
  tabBarLabel: 'News',
  header: null,
  tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => (
    <TabBarIcon
      focused={focused}
      name={
        Platform.OS === 'ios'
          ? `ios-information-circle${focused ? '' : '-outline'}`
          : 'md-information-circle'
      }
    />
  ),
};

const AbosStack = createStackNavigator({
  Abos: AboScreen,
});

AbosStack.navigationOptions = {
  tabBarLabel: 'Abos',
  header: null,
  tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => (
    <TabBarIcon
      focused={focused}
      name={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? `ios-link${focused ? '' : '-outline'}` : 'md-link'}
    />
  ),
};

const MomentsStack = createStackNavigator({
  Moments: MomentsScreen,
});

MomentsStack.navigationOptions = {
  tabBarLabel: 'Moments',
  header: null,
  tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => (
    <TabBarIcon
      focused={focused}
      name={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? `ios-options${focused ? '' : '-outline'}` : 'md-options'}
    />
  ),
};

export default createBottomTabNavigator({
  News: NewsStack,
  Abo: AbosStack,
  Moment: MomentsStack,
});
```

I End up with following[Two Headers and cant add Icon to Header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qMzJT.png)

How can I disable the second Header and How can I add Buttons to the Header to Add some Navigation to that too?

Comment: take a look at this project, they have code samples for everything that you are trying to do: https://github.com/react-native-training/react-native-elements

Comment: Thank you, but as I see they didnt use react-navigation. My question is how to solve this with react-navigation.

Comment: they are using react-navigation on the project, im pretty sure you didnt read correctly what i said: 'they have code samples for everything that you are trying to do'

Comment: I read your message but unfortunantely they didnt use react-navigation. I searched through the whole project. I would like to do it with react-navigation.